# How to access Office365 Sharepoint (2013) Documents like News/Bulletin along with CSS content in c#?

Tags: c#, css, api, sharepoint, office365

The following code access the sharepoint list.

```
var ctx = new ClientContext("http://tests.com");
var lists = ctx.Site.RootWeb.Lists;
ctx.Load(lists);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var list in lists)
Console.WriteLine(list.News);
Console.ReadKey();
```

In lists.News, lets assume one of the fieldvalues has html body and only the html content is pulled and shown in output:

```
<html>
  <div class="ExternalClass2D015247C9464EC29A11153E0E0BAEA5">
    <h1>​Hey this is flash news</ h1> etc ...< /div>
</html>
```

Here, how to access the content of this CSS class using C#, so that there is no need to regenerate similar CSS? or otherwise, can we get reference to the CSS files, that way the css link can be referred in html ?

The goal is to fetch the HTML file, which was generated in Sharepoint using inbuilt RTF document and use it as source to show in different web application. Needed the html content and its related resources(CSS) either reference or actual copy of the content.

Comment: Did that HTML source come from a Rich Text Field? If so, there is no actual CSS class. The rendered source of this field will take the site's CSS along with any inline styling that has been applied.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking time to read my question and answer. Yes, it's the source of rich text field. I agree the rich text field is  using the default site's css files and its not accessible. Besides based on my research so far, I believe  to solve this issue and enable the flexibility to use custom css, we may reset the SharePoint default css settings to use alternate user provided CSS file and let the RTF generate content utilizing this new CSS. This way we can share this css file both in share point and when the html source is outsourced to another application.

Note: To change settings we would need the 'Site Collection Admin' and 'Site Admin' Access/privilege enabled. The CSS settings are changed under 'Master Page' settings.

New file is added by clicking on 'Site Content' on main page. Windows explorer option can be used to create/import new css file.